# How to animate the image in background after the home button is pressed?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm new in ios development. I'm using wheel images in my project.The animation is working fine in foreground mode. After that I pressed the home button.now i relaunch the app the wheel animation is not working. this is my code:

```
CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"]; animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2*M_PI];
animation.duration = 1.0f;
animation.repeatCount = INFINITY;
[imageLeft.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SpinAnimation"];
```

Comment: How did you do you animation? Post some code. The question posted now is to vague to gif you a correct answer.

Comment: CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
 animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
 animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2*M_PI];
 animation.duration = 1.0f;
 animation.repeatCount = INFINITY;
 [imageLeft.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SpinAnimation"];

Comment: You should edit in your question.

Comment: CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];    animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f]; animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2*M_PI]; animation.duration = 1.0f;                       animation.repeatCount = INFINITY;                       [imageLeft.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SpinAnimation"];

Comment: is there any way to animate the image in background mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(addAnimation:) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];

}

- (void)addAnimation:(NSNotification *)notificaiton
 {
 CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
 animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2*M_PI];
 animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
 animation.duration = 4.0f;
 animation.repeatCount = INFINITY;
 [imageLeft.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SpinAnimation"];
 [imageRight.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SpinAnimation"];
 }
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

//How to remove an observer for NSNotification

      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

When your app is suspended (send to the background) all animation and timer are sopped. This is to save battery.
When your app is brought to the foreground you must start the animation again your self.

You can us the `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` in the app delegate for this.

Or listen for the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` notification in the view controller which holds the animation.

Comment: I'm recording audio.The wheel image is rotating in foreground mode.Now  i pressed the home button. The audio recorder recording the audio in background mode.when i relaunch the app the recorder recording the audio.but the wheel animation is not rotating.

Comment: And this is normal, because as I said in my answer all animation are stopped. You will just need to restart them when you come back to the foreground. Just implement the `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` App delegate.

Comment: what is the code i want to use this app delegate method               - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application.      how to restart the animation.

Comment: You recreate you `CABasicAnimation` and add it to your layer again.